# Problem with FMDB and insert value in the "executeQuery:" from a searchString

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, fmdb

While building a Search for my app i ran into a problem whilst using the FMDB SQLite Wrapper (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

When I search my database with this SQL Command, everything is fine. 13 objects are returned and I can use them.

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM ZARTICLE WHERE ZTITLEDE LIKE '%Daimler%'"];
```

But when i try to insert the searchQuery from the User Input like this:

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM ZARTICLE WHERE ZTITLEDE LIKE (?)", theSearchQuery];
```

... the value is dont be inserted into SQL Command. And I dont get any returned objects from the DB. even if the String (theSearchQuery) is the same written in the first example.

Additionaly I post a part from the documentation of FMDB for your convinience. :)

```
Data Sanitization
```

When providing a SQL statement to FMDB, you should not attempt to "sanitize" any values before insertion. Instead, you should use the standard SQLite binding syntax:

INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (?, ?, ?)
The ? character is recognized by SQLite as a placeholder for a value to be inserted. The execution methods all accept a variable number of arguments (or a representation of those arguments, such as an NSArray or a va_list), which are properly escaped for you.

Thus, you SHOULD NOT do this (or anything like this):

[db executeUpdate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (%@)", @"this has \" lots of ' bizarre \" quotes '"]];
Instead, you SHOULD do:

[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (?)", @"this has \" lots of ' bizarre \" quotes '"];
All arguments provided to the -executeUpdate: method (or any of the variants that accept a va_list as a parameter) must be objects. The following will not work (and will result in a crash):

[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (?)", 42];
The proper way to insert a number is to box it in an NSNumber object:

[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (?)", [NSNumber numberWithInt:42]];
Alternatively, you can use the -execute*WithFormat: variant to use NSString-style substitution:

[db executeUpdateWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (%d)", 42];
Internally, the -execute*WithFormat: methods are properly boxing things for you. The following percent modifiers are recognized: %@, %c, %s, %d, %D, %i, %u, %U, %hi, %hu, %qi, %qu, %f, %g, %ld, %lu, %lld, and %llu. Using a modifier other than those will have unpredictable results. If, for some reason, you need the % character to appear in your SQL statement, you should use %%.

Comment: ok i solved this:
I prepared the whole SQL Command in an extra [NSString stringWithFormat:] so i left the possibility to use the FMDB inserts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSString *search_text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%", theSearchQuery];

FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM ZARTICLE WHERE ZTITLEDE LIKE ?", search_text];
```

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend to avoid creating queries with stringWithFormat:! There is a good reason why FMDB tries to force you to use their data sanitization. However, since FMDB is boxing your input, surrounding parenthesis in the following code are not needed and may cause your problem.

```
[db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM ZARTICLE WHERE ZTITLEDE LIKE (?)", theSearchQuery];
```

Simple add arguments without any parenthisis because you never know how FMDB boxes your argument internally.

```
[db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM ZARTICLE WHERE ZTITLEDE LIKE ?", theSearchQuery];
```

If this still doesn't work try to use the suggested executeQueryWithFormat: method of FMDB:

```
[db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM ZARTICLE WHERE ZTITLEDE LIKE %@", theSearchQuery];
```

Comment: Thank you for that! but it doesnt work. so i prepared an extra String before and now it is working ... dunno why the question mark isnt working for me. the explanation on git hub was very clear and easy to follow but anways thanks!

Comment: I don't see any other way of incorporating the wild card characters into the substitution without using stringWithFormat. The where is using LIKE in this case, so, how else would you go about including the % characters that you'd expect to wrap the match string in this case?

Comment: I am not quite sure if I got you right, but you can use %% if you want to use the %-sign in your SQL.